An unusual archery contest scored by determinant
I had a dream last night where there was an archery contest held in three rounds with fixed duration, with three possible targets to aim for.  The unusual thing about it was that the final score would be the determinant of the matrix where the $ij$ entry is the number of hits on target $i$ in round $j$.
So, the question becomes: Let's suppose you're a skilled enough archer that you can shoot 30 total targets in each round (and switching targets doesn't impose any penalty).  How then do you maximize your score?

First of all, the determinant is equal to $\lVert A_{\cdot 1} \rVert \, \lVert A_{\cdot 2} \rVert \, \lVert A_{\cdot 3} \rVert \sin (\theta_1) \sin(\theta_2)$, where $\theta_1$ is the angle between columns 1 and 2, and $\theta_2$ is the angle between column 3 and the plane spanned by columns 1 and 2.  Also, since each entry is nonnegative, we have $\lVert A_{\cdot j} \rVert^2 = \sum_{i=1}^3 A_{ij}^2 \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^3 A_{ij} \right)^2 \le 30^2$.  Therefore, the determinant is at most $30^3$.  On the other hand, this value for the determinant is achieved, for example, if in each round $i$ you just hit target $i$ 30 times.  (And in fact, it's easy to see that the maximum is achieved only with some permutation of this strategy, where in round $i$ you hit target $\sigma(i)$ 30 times.)
